# BeautifulSoup, comand .findAll

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, findall

I have a problem. When using the `.find` command, the library works as it should and finds the right parts of the text from the site. But when using `.findAll`, the code breaks and does not want to work, referring to the fact that there is only one element in the code. But this is not so, the element that I am looking for, and the subsequent elements, there are a lot of them and I need the library to be able to find them. I'm new and can't figure out why the library can't find my elements, there are 50 of them each.

```
ru_name = soup.find('div', class_='styles_root__ti07r').find('div', class_='base-movie-main-info_mainInfo__ZL_u3').find('span', class_='styles_mainTitle__IFQyZ styles_activeMovieTittle__kJdJj').text
ru_name 
'Зеленая миля'
```

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-211-d7087d0255dc> in <module>
----> 1 original_name = soup.findAll('div', class_='styles_main__Y8zDm styles_mainWithNotCollapsedBeforeSlot__x4cWo').find('span', class_='desktop-list-main-info_secondaryTitle__ighTt').text
      2 original_name

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/bs4/element.py in __getattr__(self, key)
   1881 
   1882     def __getattr__(self, key):
-> 1883         raise AttributeError(
   1884             "ResultSet object has no attribute '%s'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?" % key
   1885         )

AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?
```

```
original_name = soup.find('div', class_='styles_main__Y8zDm styles_mainWithNotCollapsedBeforeSlot__x4cWo').find('span', class_='desktop-list-main-info_secondaryTitle__ighTt').text
original_name
```

```
remain = soup.find('div', class_='styles_main__Y8zDm styles_mainWithNotCollapsedBeforeSlot__x4cWo').find('span', class_='desktop-list-main-info_truncatedText__IMQRP').text
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Case "styles_root__ti07r", not just one, there are many of them, specifically 50 pieces, and why the find. All commands do not work, I don’t understand

Answer (score 0):

*In newer code avoid old syntax `findAll()` instead use `find_all()` or `select()` with `css selectors` - For more take a minute to [check docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#method-names)*

> AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?

You have to iterate your `ResultSet` to use `find()` on each element:

```
for e in soup.find_all('div', class_='styles_main__Y8zDm styles_mainWithNotCollapsedBeforeSlot__x4cWo'):
    print(e.find('span', class_='desktop-list-main-info_secondaryTitle__ighTt').text)
```

Comment: Thanks, your function helped. I just do it according to the guide and it says `findAll`, a year has passed since the guide, a little outdated.

Comment: With pleasure!!!